# how to use piwik javascript code in app.js on express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, matomo

I want to use javascript code of piwik to track my website which is built on express.
I had put my javascript code in app.js in express.
But found error.

my javascript code is:-

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
             var _paq = _paq || [];
             _paq.push(["trackPageView"]);
           _paq.push(["enableLinkTracking"]);

       (function() {
           var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "://localhost/piwik/";
        _paq.push(["setTrackerUrl", u+"piwik.php"]);
        _paq.push(["setSiteId", "1"]);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement("script"), s=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; g.type="text/javascript";
         g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+"piwik.js";   s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
          })();
      </script>
```

Comment: What error did you find?

Comment: var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http")
                               ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the client-side code for Piwik directly on Node.js.

But there are specific Node clients that you can use instead:

- [`nodejs-piwik`](https://github.com/fvdm/nodejs-piwik)
- [`nodejs-piwik-api`](https://github.com/willyl/nodejs-piwik-api)

Comment: I had tried using this option..but where do i define campaign parameters

Comment: @user3016262 sorry, can't help you with that, I have no idea